# Integral to Gamma function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, gamma-function, beta-function

For this function i need to convert it to either a Gamma or a Beta function
$$\int_0^1 \frac{3}{(1-x^3)^\frac{1}{3}} \,dx$$

I know I need to make the substitution $x^3=z$ but I am unsure where to go from here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For simplicity, define

$$\mathcal I := \int_0^1 \frac{3}{(1-x^3)^\frac{1}{3}} \,dx$$

Make the $u$-substitution $u=x^3$ as you prescribed. Then:

- $x = u^{1/3}$
- $dx = \frac 1 3 u^{-2/3} du$

Insert both of these definitions into the integral and pull out constants via linearity. (They happen to cancel.) We find that

$$\mathcal I = \int_0^1 u^{-2/3} (1-u)^{-1/3}du$$

Recall that the definition of the beta function is given by

$$\text B(x,y) := \int_0^1 t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1}dt$$

$\mathcal I$ now matches this same form for appropriate $x,y$:

- $-2/3 = x-1 \implies x = 1/3$
- $-1/3 = y-1 \implies y = 2/3$

Thus,

$$\mathcal I = \text B \left( \frac 1 3, \frac 2 3 \right) \approx 3.6276$$

WolframAlpha numerically confirms this answer: [their answer for the integral](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+from+0+to+1+of+3%2F%281-x%5E3%29%5E%281%2F3%29+dx) and for the [beta function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=beta+function+%281%2F3%2C2%2F3%29) are at the links. If you want to convert to a gamma function version, note the identity

$$\text B(x,y) = \frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}$$

In this case, then (since $\Gamma(1/3 + 2/3) = \Gamma(1) = 1$),

$$\mathcal I = \Gamma \left( \frac 1 3 \right) \Gamma \left( \frac 2 3 \right)$$

We can even simplify this result further by use of Euler's reflection formula and get a better closed form. The reflection formula is given by

$$\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z) = \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)}$$

Take $z = 1/3$ and how it might be utilized for $\mathcal I$ is clear. Then

$$\mathcal I = \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi/3)} = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{3} / 2} = \frac{2 \pi}{\sqrt 3}$$

*(Credits to user Ty who pointed out the simplification owing to Euler's reflection formula in the comments!)*

Comment: You can simplify this even further to $\frac{2 \pi}{\sqrt{3}}$ using euler’s reflection formula.

Comment: Ooooh, nice eye Ty! I'll add that in a bit!